# Rich snippet (reviews) not showing in Google

Tags: google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I am pretty new with 'Rich snippets'. I did create a snippet on the page: https://www.vanloonautobedrijf.nl/recensies/

I am using the following code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="shopReview">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "vanloonautobedrijf.nl",
      "url": "https://www.vanloonautobedrijf.nl",
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.1",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "worstRating": "1",
        "reviewCount": "430"
      }
    }
```

But the stars are not showing in Google even after waiting a week they still don't show. Does someone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It might take (way) longer than a week.

Comment: @unor after the recent changes, maybe never.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to supplement good answer of *Tony McCreath*. 
The **[AggregateRating type specification](https://schema.org/AggregateRating)** tells us:

> The average rating based on multiple ratings or reviews.

However, the webpage you specified does not have a single review. This web page has only some information from a third party website. This information is set in iframe:

```html
<iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://autobedrijf.tevreden.nl/cgi-bin/react_tool.pl?Op=Widget&template=reviews&vestigingID=autobedrijf5325kg7&height=459&width=400&limit_last_year=0&autoheight=1&num_reviews=3"  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This contradicts the following **[Google guidelines for the type Review](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet#technical-guidelines)**:

> If the review snippet is for a local business or an organization, you
>   must follow these additional guidelines:
>
> - Ratings must be sourced directly from users.
> - Sites must collect ratings information directly from users and not from other sites

Answer (score 0):

Organization entities can no longer get review stars if the markup is on the the organizations own site:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

"Pages using LocalBusiness or any other type of Organization structured data are ineligible for star review feature if the entity being reviewed controls the reviews about itself. For example, a review about entity A is placed on the website of entity A, either directly in their structured data or through an embedded third-party widget."